# Refiring an event when dynamic html is loaded?

Tags: jquery

I have div#1 that is clickable and expands another div#2. Now when div#2 loads dynamic htmlbut at the same time div#1 has dynamic text ... on first load the expand event fires, but when the dynamic data is written it re-writes div#1 and div#2 so afterwards it does not fire the expand event?

Answer (score 0):

See: http://api.jquery.com/live/